# Swapping elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, swap

I'm trying to make a somewhat slider puzzle kind of game where you click 1 image, then click another and they swap positions. For some reason this works correctly the first time you do it, but when you go to swap an image for the second time and every time after that it selects a different element than the one that you clicked on. Any help would be appreachated, thank you.

```
public class test extends Application {
int click1 = -1, click2 = -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //Create a GridPane
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setHgap(5);
    pane.setVgap(5);

    //create ArrayList and add imageList to ArrayList
    ArrayList<ImageView>imageList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        imageList.add(new ImageView ((i) +".jpg"));
    }       

    addImages(imageList, pane);

    //add onClick listeners to each image
    imageList.get(0).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(0, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(1).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(1, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(2).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(2, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(3).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(3, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(4).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(4, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(5).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(5, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(6).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(6, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(7).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(7, imageList, pane);
    });
    imageList.get(8).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        swap(8, imageList, pane);
    });

    //display the scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 650, 650);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void swap(int lastClick, ArrayList<ImageView> imageList, GridPane pane) {
    if (click1 == -1) {
        click1 = lastClick;
        System.out.println(imageList.get(click1).getImage().impl_getUrl()+ " ");

        imageList.get(click1).setScaleX(1.02);
        imageList.get(click1).setScaleY(1.02);
    } else {
        click2 = lastClick;
        System.out.println(imageList.get(click2).getImage().impl_getUrl()+ " ");

        //swap indexes in ArrayList
        Collections.swap(imageList, click2, click1);
        pane.getChildren().removeAll(imageList);
        addImages(imageList, pane);

        //reset everything for next swap
        imageList.get(click1).setScaleX(1.0);
        imageList.get(click1).setScaleY(1.0);
        imageList.get(click2).setScaleX(1.0);
        imageList.get(click2).setScaleY(1.0);           
        click1 = -1;
        click2 = -1;
    }
}

private void addImages(ArrayList<ImageView> imageList, GridPane pane) {
    //add imageList to the GridPane
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 9) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
                pane.add(imageList.get(i), k, j);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Update the mouseclick listener once you click on it with the new index.

Comment: You are amazing! I'm not too sure why that made it work though, if you wouldn't mind could you explain a little so I can understand it better? Thank you so much though I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the mouseclick listener once you update the new element. What ends up happening is a stale state. An item that has moved reports its initial position rather than its actual position, resulting in your items moving around to where they shouldn't be.

Basic State.

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

Assume we click 3 and then 5. The request is to swap image 5 to image 3's slot, and image 3 to image 5's slot.

`0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8`

This looks right for now, but let's try another swap. Let's swap image 1 with 5.

`0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8`

What happened?! 1 and 5 were clicked, but 3 and 1 swapped places instead!

The move on the back-end worked actually worked exactly as designed. Image 5 and Image 1 were clicked, resulting in the operation "swap **slot 5** with **slot 1**, instead of the intended **slot 3** with **slot 1**. The issue with that is that the image in slot 5 is actually image 3.

The rectification for this is to update the mouse click listeners to know where they are afterwards, so they can report their new, updated positions.

Fix would be:

```
imageList.get(click1).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
    swap(click1, imageList, pane);
});
imageList.get(click2).setOnMouseClicked(e->{
    swap(click2, imageList, pane);
});
```

This tells the swapped items that "This is where you are moved, and from now on you should report that this is your new moved position."